# Unexpected token 'case' (switch statement)

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm making a hotspot, and which is using Ajax to log the user into the router.

If there is a problem with connecting to the network, it should pop up an alert which says there is a problem, please contact the reception.

I'm using a switch statement, which displays the message depending on the clients language / selected language.

I've got a bunch of switch statements in the rest of my code, and they all work fine, but here I'm getting an error, that...

> Uncough SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'case'

Any help and explenation of why this error occures only here would be greatly appriciated. Thank you

```
function Ajax1 (method, url){
    return new Promise (function (resolve,  reject){
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://10.5.50.1/login', true);
        xhr.onload = function(){
            if(this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300){
                resolve(xhr.response);
            }else{
                reject({
                //  console.log("XHR1 " + this.readyState);
                //  console.log("XHR1 " + this.status);
                    switch (global){
                        case "sl":
                            alert("Prišlo je do napake. Prosim obrnite se na recepcijo.");
                            break;
                        case "en":
                            alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                            break;
                        case "de":
                            alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                            break;
                        case "it":
                            alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                            break;
                        case "hr":
                            alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                            break;
                        case "ru":
                            alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                            break;
                        default:
                            alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function (){
            reject({
            //  console.log("XHR1 " + this.readyState);
            //  console.log("XHR1 " + this.status);
                switch (global){
                    case "sl":
                        alert("Prišlo je do napake. Prosim obrnite se na recepcijo.");
                        break;
                    case "en":
                        alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                        break;
                    case "de":
                        alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                        break;
                    case "it":
                        alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                        break;
                    case "hr":
                        alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                        break;
                    case "ru":
                        alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                }
            });
        };

        console.log("sent");
        xhr.send("username=HSuser&password=SimpleUserPassword");
    });
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error happening on? Usually it means there's something wrong on the line before.

Comment: You can't put a `switch` statement inside an object literal.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a `switch` statement inside the argument to `reject()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switch` is a statement, not an expression. It can't be used in an object literal or the argument to a function. You need to take it out of the `reject()` argument.

```
            }else{
                switch (global){
                    case "sl":
                        alert("Prišlo je do napake. Prosim obrnite se na recepcijo.");
                        break;
                    case "en":
                        alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                        break;
                    case "de":
                        alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                        break;
                    case "it":
                        alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                        break;
                    case "hr":
                        alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                        break;
                    case "ru":
                        alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("There seems to be an issues. Please contact the reception.");
                }
                reject();
            }
```